# Does a break statement break from a switch/select?

Tags: select, switch-statement, go, break

I know that `switch`/`select` statements break automatically after every case. I am wondering, in the following code:

```
for {
    switch sometest() {
    case 0:
        dosomething()
    case 1:
        break
    default:
        dosomethingelse()
    }
}
```

Does the `break` statement exit the `for` loop or just the `switch` block?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

> [Break statements, The Go Programming Language Specification.](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements)
>
> A "break" statement terminates execution of the innermost "for",
>   "switch" or "select" statement.
>
> ```
> BreakStmt = "break" [ Label ] .
> ```
>
> If there is a label, it must be that of an enclosing "for", "switch"
>   or "select" statement, and that is the one whose execution terminates
>   (§For statements, §Switch statements, §Select statements).
>
> ```
> L:
>   for i < n {
>       switch i {
>       case 5:
>           break L
>       }
>   }
> ```

Therefore, the `break` statement in your example terminates the `switch` statement, the "innermost" statement.

Comment: What's the use case of the `break` within `select {}` since only one `case` can be selected?

Comment: Because even if a single case is selected, it might have a longer implementation which uses break to terminate the execution of the case, much like you can return from anywhere in a function.

Comment: Also the `n` might be big so you want to get out of the loop soon.

Answer (score 89):

A hopefully illustrative example:

```
loop:
for {
        switch expr {
        case foo:
                if condA {
                        doA()
                        break // like 'goto A'
                }

                if condB {
                        doB()
                        break loop // like 'goto B'                        
                }

                doC()
        case bar:
                // ...
        }
A:
        doX()
        // ...
}

B:
doY()
// ....
```

Answer (score 29):

Yes, `break` breaks the inner `switch`.

https://play.golang.org/p/SZdDuVjic4

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

myloop:
    for x := 0; x < 7; x++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d", x)
        switch {
        case x == 1:
            fmt.Println("start")
        case x == 5:
            fmt.Println("stop")
            break myloop
        case x > 2:
            fmt.Println("crunching..")
            break
        default:
            fmt.Println("idling..")
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> 0idling..
> 1start
> 2idling..
> 3crunching..
> 4crunching..
> 5stop
>
> Program exited.
> ```

Comment: this answer does not demonstrate how the `break` statement without label can be useful. the `break` statement in `case x > 2:` is effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 25):

This question might be too old already but I still think label makes our code become harder to read.
Instead of breaking the for inside select, just set a flag for the loop and handle it inside select-case before invoking break.
For example:

```golang
loop := true
for loop {
    select {
    case <-msg:
        // do your task here
    case <-ctx.Done():
        loop = false
        break
    }
}
```

**Updated:** Totally agree with Vaelin in the comment. Declaring that flag inside the scope of the for loop can avoid memory leak and conflict with other variables in current scope, just in case we have a same variable name already.

```golang
for loop := true; loop; {

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to leak the loop variable you can also declare it inside the scope of the for loop `for loop := true; loop; {}`. Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dNChUECkbfd

Answer (score 8):

Just from a switch block. There's plenty of examples in Golang own code you can examine (compare [inner break](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/6185cb1f3105899cd34484c59407846bec0acc06/cmd/goyacc/yacc.go#L1397) with [outer break](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/6185cb1f3105899cd34484c59407846bec0acc06/cmd/goyacc/yacc.go#L406)).

Answer (score 3):

this should explain it.

```
for{
    x := 1
    switch {
    case x >0:
        fmt.Println("sjus")
    case x == 1:
        fmt.Println("GFVjk")
    default:
        fmt.Println("daslkjh")
    }
}
}
```

Runs forever

```
for{
    x := 1
    switch {
    case x >0:
        fmt.Println("sjus")
        break
    case x == 1:
        fmt.Println("GFVjk")
    default:
        fmt.Println("daslkjh")
    }
}
}
```

Again, runs forever

BUT

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
d:
for{
x := 1
    switch {
    case x >0:
        fmt.Println("sjus")
        break d
    case x == 1:
        fmt.Println("GFVjk")
    default:
        fmt.Println("daslkjh")
    }
}
}
```

will print sjus
... clear ?

http://play.golang.org/p/GOvnfI67ih

Comment: hmmm I included a go play link, which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It only exits the switch block.