# IF there is a small moment between the first iteration and the second iteration

Tags: go

In the code below, iterations are runned two times.
Is it possible that "test2 <- true" is runned at the moment which is just between the first iteration and the second iteration?
I mean, is there a change to send true to "test2" when the first iteration is ended and the second iteration is not started?

```
package main

import "log"
import "time"

func main() {
    test := make(chan bool, 1)
    test2 := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-test:
                log.Println("test")
            case <-test2:
                log.Println("test2")
            }
        }
    }()

    test <- true
    time.Sleep(1)
    test2 <- true
    time.Sleep(1)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since your channels are buffered and can hold 1 value. the main execution flow can continue without your anonymous goroutine reading the value you send to the `test` channel, and it can send a value on the `test2` channel before the goroutine wakes up and read the value on the `test` channel.

This is unlikely to happen, since you have a time.Sleep() call there to normally give time for the goroutine to execute, but there's no telling what'll happen in a corner case of your machine being very busy, being power suspended at an (un)lucky time or other things you didn't think about.

If your `test` channel was unbuffered, the `test <- true` statement would block until your goroutine received the value, and there would at least be no possibility for the goroutine to receive from `test2` before receiving anything from the `test` channel.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974131/6309), you can simulate that case (where "`test2 <- true`" is run at the moment which is just between the first iteration and the second iteration") easily enough by making your first message reception  (`case <- test`) wait one second.

```
case <-test:
    log.Println("test")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
```

By the time the anonymous goroutine wakes up, `main()` has already sent its two messages to the two buffered channel (buffer means non-blokcing for *one* message), and exited.
If `main()` exits, everything else, including the goroutine which was busy sleeping, stops.

See <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/JanXW1N9yF)</kbd>: the output would be:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 test
```

You wouldn't have the time to see `test2`.

---

In order to make sure your goroutine can process *both* message, you need:

- `main()` to wait for said goroutine to finish. That is where the [`sync` package](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) comes into play, using (for instance, this isn't the only solution) a [`WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) directive.

  ```
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
      // Decrement the counter when the goroutine completes.
      defer wg.Done()
      ...
  }
  ... // end of main():
  // Wait for goroutine to complete.
  wg.Wait()
  ```
- the goroutine to actually exit at some time (instead of being stuck in the `for` loop forever). See "[In Go, does a break statement break from a switch/select?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11104085/6309)"

  ```
  loop:                                  <==========
  for {
      select {
      case <-test:
          log.Println("test")
          time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
      case <-test2:
          log.Println("test2")
          break loop                     <==========
      }
  }
  ```

See <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/n9cRpYK3ue)</kbd>: the message `test2` is sent while the goroutine is sleeping after `test1`, but `main()` will wait (`wg.Wait()`), and the goroutine will have its chance to read and print `test2` one second later.

The output is:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 test
2009/11/10 23:00:01 test2  // one second later
```