# About the order of channels

Tags: go

I ran the code below several times and sometimes "test" was printed after "test2".
Why is that?
I think "true" is sent to "test" first.

```
package main

import "log"
import "time"

func main() {
    test := make(chan bool, 1)
    test2 := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-test:
                log.Println("test")
            case <-test2:
                log.Println("test2")
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    test <- true
    test2 <- true
    time.Sleep(1)
}
```

**Edited 2014/7/27:**

After reading the [article](http://golang.org/ref/mem), I think that each of "test <- true" and "test2 <- true" could be "happens-before" or "happens-after" or also "happens-concurrently".

Comment: possible duplicate of [IF there is a small moment between the first iteration and the second iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973935/if-there-is-a-small-moment-between-the-first-iteration-and-the-second-iteration)

Comment: You could have edited the first question, please don't repost the same question within 10 minutes.

Comment: It's not the same question actually.

Answer (score 1):

"If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection." You are seeing a uniform pseudo-random selection.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Select statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
>
> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1) For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive
>   operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>   statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>   the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive
>   from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side
>   effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any)
>   communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the
>   left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or
>   assignment are not yet evaluated.
>
> 2) If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that
>   can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.
>   Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>   is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>   of the communications can proceed.
>
> 3) Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective
>   communication operation is executed.
>
> 4) If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable
>   declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are
>   evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
>
> 5) The statement list of the selected case is executed.
>
> Since communication on nil channels can never proceed, a select with
>   only nil channels and no default case blocks forever.

Comment: I don't know why two communications (test <- true and test2 <-true) happen at the same time in this code. I added "time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)" before "test <- true", so I suppose that the goroutine becomes "waiting a value mode" before "test <- true" is runned for sure. But still sometimes "test" is printed after "test2".

Comment: I suppose, the execution order is 1."select " 2."test <- true" 3."<-test' .

Comment: @TaichiSato: test <- true; test2 <- true; select.

Comment: I've added "time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)" by the way.

Comment: @TaichiSato: No. Try changing [runtime.GOMAXPROCS](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS).

Comment: @TaichiSato: goroutine; select (block) ; test <- true; test2 <- true; select (execute).

Comment: "select (execute)" is always after "test2 <- true" ?

Comment: Sending and receiving on a channel is not atomic?