# How to implement non-blocking write to an unbuffered channel?

Tags: go, channel

From [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels)

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive. If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.

But [signal.Notify](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify) relays signals to an unbuffered channel without blocking. How does this work and is it possible to do with other chan<- types ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What it means when it says `os.Notify` will not block is the messages will be dropped were it to block. So while it's true that it doesn't block, it's not true that it will relay the signals if they can't be received immediately. This is done via simple `select`:

```
select {
    case channel <- message:
        // message sent
    default:
        // message dropped
}
```

Which is why the documentation for `Notify` explicitly states that you should use a buffered channel. Also note that buffered channels can also block, not just unbuffered channels; buffered channels only block if the buffer is already full.

`select` is covered in [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) and [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements).

Comment: Ah ok. Got stuck in the rut of using select to read from channels - didn't think beyond. I see the [relevant bits](https://golang.org/src/os/signal/signal.go?s=5402:5481) now.

Comment: Incidentally, this same style of a select with a default case can be used to safely close channels in situations where they might be closed more than once (since closing a closed channel causes a panic).  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/vDBovMHMKT-.  If the channel close can possible be run concurrently, however, you need to protect it with a mutex: https://play.golang.org/p/f8mg602rOVF

Comment: @Kaedys That's not necessary. Just use `sync.Once`.

Answer (score 6):

You can always avoid blocking while (probably) still guaranteeing delivery by using another goroutine:

```
go func() { channel <- message }()
```

Of course, this is just using the goroutine scheduler as a substitute buffer for your channel, which may or may not be wise.

Comment: Nitpick: Wouldn't this channel and blocked goroutine be in the memory (till the program ends) , if nobody ever happens to read from the channel ?

Comment: That is correct.  A major disadvantage compared to a buffered channel is that the goroutine won't be garbage collected if it's left blocked and no one else is referencing it.  My suggestion is just a simple way to avoid blocking on an unbuffered channel while maximizing the chances of still delivering the message.

Comment: This potentially leaks go routines. Please do not use this faulty answer. @JeremyHuiskamp

Comment: That downside is clearly discussed in the comments above.  That said, there are situations where this would be fine (eg, you know how many goroutines you are going to spawn and/or you have some limited time that your program will be running, like a commandline tool). I would definitely never use this in a backend application, or any library.

Comment: Consider that the items may be out of order in the channel

Answer (score 0):

> Which is why the documentation for Notify explicitly states that you should use a buffered channel

With [Go 1.17](https://twitter.com/golang/status/1403016905179422723), [the tool `vet`](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.17#vet) will also make that clearer:

> ### New warning for calling signal.Notify on unbuffered channels
>
> The `vet` tool now warns about calls to `signal.Notify` with incoming signals being sent to an unbuffered channel.
>
> Using an unbuffered channel risks missing signals sent on them as `signal.Notify` does not block when sending to a channel.
>
> For example:
>
> ```golang
> c := make(chan os.Signal)
> // signals are sent on c before the channel is read from.
> // This signal may be dropped as c is unbuffered.
> signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
> ```
>
> Users of `signal.Notify` should use channels with sufficient buffer space to keep up with the expected signal rate.

Answer (score 0):

So, this doesn't answer directly to the problem since it asks for a unbuffered channel, but if all you want is for it not to block on send, this is what I came up with:

```
ch := make(chan shared.BlogPost, 1024)
```

You just put a number larger than expected. If you don't know in advance the maximum capacity, then this solution might not work for you.

Also remember that go allocates the channel eagerly, so be careful with memory usage.